# "School with ID “601664bd3c7d8d38768c43b9” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?" Error when migrated using mongorestore

Tags: django, mongodb, database-migration, mongorestore, djongo

I want to migrate the data from a Mongodb database running with a Nodejs+mongoose platform into a Django+djongo platform. I created the data backup using mongodump and got me a .bson file which I used for migration.

data shown in source database is as follows.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c03c9f4a836690d6c540835"),
    "title" : "School A",
    "location" : "Location A",
    "postTime" : "1543752160981",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-23T16:47:43Z"),
    "verified" : true,
    "__v" : 0,
    "image" : "http://21.441.45.80:3002/images/1543752161789-file.jpg",
    "thumbnail" : "http://21.441.45.80:3002/images/thumnail-1543752161789-file.jpg"
}
```

I created the destination database with similar fields avoiding "__v". I imported the source data into destination database using following command.

```
mongorestore --db school_db --collection school_schoolmodel ../path/to/school.bson
```

I got message that

`1169 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.`
Then I opened the django admin panel, and clicked one of the item. Then I got following error?

`School with ID “601664bd3c7d8d38768c43b9” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?`

What is the issue here?

I'm putting code here. Please comment if any additional details required.
I'm not allowed to change the configuration of source database.

**models.py**

```
class NewsModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, serialize=False,
                          verbose_name='Company Code')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(blank=True)
    postTime = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=thumb_image_upload_to, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'School'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Schools'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the primary keys must have changed during the data migration.

**Update**
I created a new record using django admin app and I compared the primary key field with the migrated record. In the migrated field, the _id value was shown as string and was not a ObjectId().